# make : filter display to show only error

Tags: makefile, ubuntu-16.04

I've got a Makefile pretty big, and it have some errors/warnings.

My objective is to filter the display to show **only** the error of the Makefile; it will help me a lot for debugging and executed this Makefile good by saving a lot of time.

There is something of 40+ errors and 100+ warnings, so it's just a pain to see all warnings and is really difficult to determine if a correction of the Makefile works good or bad

---

I have already tried to use the `grep` command with `make | grep error`, but the display is the same (all warnings are printed).

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: If you're using `bash` then try `make 2>&1 | grep error` -- `make` outputs diagnostics on `stderr` rather than `stdout`.

Comment: that little tip works fine, I let you write the answer, I will accept it when you will done it

Comment: It's important to get the terms & ideas right.  None of these messages are being generated by `make`.  They are all generated from your compiler, which make is invoking.  So to say "make outputs diagnostics on stderr" is not correct: it's the compiler which is doing that.  What you COULD do with make is modify your recipe so that it isn't shown: this shows just the errors and warnings and not the compile lines.  Or you could modify the recipe to just print a short output per file like "CC foo.c" and not the full compile line.